# City names as column title

Tags: sql, pivot

I have two tables.

```
Food Table
--------------------------
ID     CityID    FoodName
--------------------------
1      1         FoodA
2      1         FoodB
3      1         FoodC
4      2         FoodW
5      2         FoodX
6      2         FoodY
7      2         FoodZ

City Table
--------------------------
ID     CityName
--------------------------
1      Memphis
2      Nashville
3      Chattanooga
```

So How can I use **CityName** s as Column title and list the food in that city.

```
--------------------------------------
Memphis     Nashville     Chattanooga
--------------------------------------
FoodA       FoodW         
FoodB       FoodX
FoodC       FoodY
            FoodZ
```

I'm pretty sure on that I have to use pivot but I couldn't find a good solution yet.
This is what I've achieved so far.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Food F
    INNER JOIN City C ON C.ID = F.CityID
    ) DataTable D
PIVOT(F.FoodName FOR C.CityName IN (
            [Memphis]
            ,[Nashville]
            ,[Chattanooga]
            )) PivotTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this query to get your output. Actually you did some mistakes to setup the pivot query.

```
select Memphis,Nashville,Chattanooga 
from
(
  select f.ID,c.CityName,f.FoodName 
  from Food f 
  inner join City c 
   on f.CityID=c.id
)result 
pivot
(
  max(FoodName) 
  for CityName in(Memphis,Nashville,Chattanooga)
) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PIVOT` operator uses the columns from the data table that are not in the `PIVOT` definition as `GROUP` anchor.
That mean that two values will be in the same row of a `PIVOT` table when they have the same value in the columns of data table that are neither the aggregated one or the pivoted one.
The OP data don't have this value so a new partitioned id is generated.

```
SELECT Memphis, Nashville, Chattanooga
FROM   (SELECT c.CityName, f.FoodName 
             , FoodID = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY FoodName)
        FROM   Food f
               INNER JOIN City c ON f.CityID = c.id) d 
       PIVOT
       (MAX(FoodName) FOR CityName IN (Memphis,Nashville,Chattanooga)) pvt
```